# Creating many profiles using android

Tags: android, database, android-intent, android-sqlite

I have created a screen which will take the input from the user such as name, address, etc. I am storing this information using IDs in the database table. So I can retrieve this information using IDs. 
Now my problem,
After creating an account, the list of existing profiles appear and the user should click on his name for activating his account. activating his account must include retrieving his name and address. and name should appear on the next screen. 
the problem i am facing is, i have retrieved the ID of the current user using an onListItemClick event. thus the information is retrieved only when the user clicks on the name and if he click on any other button the information vanishes.
How can i retain the information of the user until he logs out?

My code:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);      
    mRowId = id;
    if (mRowId != null) {
      Intent i = new Intent(this, Main.class);
      i.putExtra("ID", mRowId);
      startActivity(i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the recommended way of doing this would be to use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref). You can store key value pairs in them that can be accessed any time very easily. You can store user name and other login info here and just access it to get the details of the current user.

So a simple algorithm might be:

- When app starts, if there is no user active, show the user creation/selection screen
- Once user creates/selects his profile, Store the user data in shared preferences and continue to next screen.

See this thread for actual usage of shared preferences:

[How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

Comment: Thanks for your help!
For all those who want to learn about shared preferences visit, it was very helpful for me!!.. Hope it helps yu'll too!:
[link](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/01/use-getsharedpreferences-to-retrieve.html)